# Excel formula that will let me show a data range in a cell based on the value in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a form where someone can choose a value from a drop down list and it will create another dropdown list in the next cell based on the first cells value. The next cells dropdown list would need to reference a cell range on a separate worksheet and only show row 4-30 as a dropdown.

Is this possible? I tried using data validation with an indirect formula but I cannot define the cell ranges as the codes start with numbers.

Any suggestions would be helpful?

Comment: Can you post something about how you tried `INDIRECT`?  This is one of the more common use cases for `INDIRECT`, and it usually works well if you name the ranges correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The Choose/Match function works well except that I have 427 columns that need to be matched which seems to be too much for data validation.

Comment: For Indirect you need to name your ranges however apparently you cannot define names if they start with a number. All my lists are codes that start with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example using *VBA*

Place this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, B1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    If Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case A1.Value
        Case "animals"
            Call SetupDV(B1, "dog,cat,bird")
        Case "days"
            Call SetupDV(B1, "monday,tuesday,wednesday")
        Case "months"
            Call SetupDV(B1, "january,february,march")
    End Select
End Sub
```

and place this macro in a standard module:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Cells.Validation.Delete
    Call SetupDV(Range("A1"), "animals,days,months")
End Sub

Sub SetupDV(MyCells As Range, st As String)
    With MyCells.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=st
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then run ***MAIN***

Whenever you make a selection from the pull-down in cell **A1**, the pull-down in cell **B1** will adjust accordingly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution for this using formulas alone, without VBA code.

Assuming your data looks like this:

[image: Dynamic validation list]

- First column selection list is Catgories, in A2:A4.
- Second column selection list will be chosen as one of C2:C6 | D2:D6 | E2:E6, by the selection of a category.
- In G2:G3 you can select a category.
- H2:H3 will show the list according to the category selected in G respectively.

The **validation list source** for H2:H3 will be defined with this formula:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(G2,$C$1:$E$1,0),$C$2:$C$6,$D$2:$D$6,$E$2:$E$6)
```

Select H2:H3, go to Data Validation, choose List and put this formula in the Source. (The range reference will be updated for H3 automatically).

#### The Formula:

The `MATCH` part returns 1,2 or 3 for the category names in C1:E1.
`CHOOSE` returns the range C, D or E respectively, according to the order they are supplied in the function.

#### Remarks:

The ranges can reference cells in another sheet by simply stating the sheet name `Sheet2!C2:C6` in the validation list formula. In earlier versions of Excel you need to name these external ranges for it to work in a validation list.

Comment: This is a very well thought out answer.